# Using begin tran / rollback / commit when updating data in multiple databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Running stored proc on database `a1`, copying data to database `a2`.
Will the rollback work correctly in case of an insert error?

```
begin tran

    update a1.dbo.customer set customer_name = 'abc' 
    where customer_no = 1234

    SELECT @errno = @@error
    IF @errno <> 0
             BEGIN
                rollback
                GOTO error
             END

    insert into a2.dbo.customer 
    select * from a1.dbo.customer where customer_no = 1234
    
    SELECT @errno = @@error
    IF @errno <> 0
             BEGIN
                rollback
                GOTO error
             END             
commit
```

Comment: The entire transaction will be rolled since SQL Server uses a local distributed transaction for cross-database updates. I suggest you use structured error handling (TRY/CATCH) rather than GOTO.

Comment: Its the kind of thing you should try and see, to gain experience, rather than just asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cross database transactions will be rolled back.